# Kusto Query Contains Operator Does Not Work With Escape Characters

Tags: azure, kql

I'm using the Azure Monitor log to query page views from app insights. When executing a Kusto query to the customDimensions field the following does not return any results:

```
pageViews
| where customDimensions contains "\"qa\""
```

Values of custom dimensions contains something like this {"Environemnt": "qa"}. Am I missing something? I have tried without the escape chars just using '"qa"' and it still doesn't work. If I try just 'qa' it returns result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for anyone interested you can use Regex instead:

```
customDimensions matches regex '"qa"'
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by escaping twice.

I ran into the issue while trying to query all rows whose name was 'total' or whose name didn't include a backslash.

First I wrote the query via Azure Data Explorer Web UI and found that the following returned the results I wanted:
`CodeCoverage | where name == "total" or name !contains "\\"` When I inspected the network request in Chrome's network logs, I saw that the body of the request included the exact same string: `CodeCoverage | where name == "total" or name !contains "\\"`.

When I copied that into my JavaScript and ran the query via the REST API, the request returned a 400 status code (bad request) with an error message telling me there was a syntax error. This happened because the query was missing a backslash: `MyTable | where name == "total" or name !contains "\"`. The escape escapes the second `"` and the first `"` has no match. The syntax is invalid. Hence the 400 status code.

The query succeeded and the request returned 200 when I escaped the backslash twice:

`MyTable | where name == "total" or name !contains "\\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Verbatim string literals

like this

- Enclose in double-quotes ("): @"This is a verbatim string literal
  that ends with a backslash"
- Enclose in single-quotes ('): @'This is a verbatim string literal
  that ends with a backslash'

here is the [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string)